# Best allocator for node-based containers?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

What's the best allocator for node-based containers like list, map and multi_map?
I've got a `boost::unordered_map<std::array<char, 32>, int>` with 4 million entries. 4 million separate allocations should be avoided (for performance).

Ideally the allocator would allocate multiple (very) large chunks and divide them into nodes with 0 per-node overhead. Free nodes should be tracked, but chunks don't need to be freed until the entire pool is destructed or reset.
The pool should not be thread-safe (for performance).

I could try to write my own but I don't like to reinvent the wheel. Not knowing the node-side beforehand seems problematic too.

Boost has Pool, but it appears to only offer singleton usage.

Comment: why are you using `malloc` in C++?

Comment: I'm not. I was trying to distinguish between the allocations done by the container and those done by the allocator itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can adapt/wrap [Loki small object allocator](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/index.php?n=Idioms.SmallObject). It is suitable for small objects of same size.
Another option is to use [Boost.Pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/pool/doc/html/index.html). It has support for object oriented (non-singleton) usage, but you will have to wrap it to an allocator object supported by `boost::unordered_map`.

Comment: Wrapping it in an allocator is the hard part (IMO).

Comment: @XTF: Implementing the allocation strategy is also a hard part. So instead of two hard parts you can do just one. :)